# jbpm 6.4 war build failed using maven tool

Tags: jbpm

I have downloaded the kie-wb-distributions-6.4.0.Final.zip from gitHub. I am trying to build the war using maven tool, but getting error like 
[ERROR] /opt/kie-wb-distributions-6.4.0.Final/kie-wb/kie-wb-webapp/target/generated-sources/annotations/org/kie/workbench/client/perspectives/DroolsAuthoringPerspectiveActivity.java:[41,7] error: duplicate class: org.kie.workbench.client.perspectives.DroolsAuthoringPerspectiveActivity

I am in kie-wb-distributions-6.4.0.Final/kie-wb folder.
Command used: mvn clean compile package for building the war.
It is compiling successfully (mvn compile).
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory for you to compile the war? I downloaded the compiled war and works fine in EAP6.4 and Wildfly8. As soon as I have free time I will try to compile the zip that is causing problems to you.

Comment: The downloaded war also worked for me works fine in both wildfly8 and 9. In my case I need to compile the project and need to build the war. please guide.

Comment: My suggestion is to open an issue on official Jbpm issue management tool here: https://issues.jboss.org/projects/JBPM